# Get the Count and Name

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

I have a class called `Cars` which has two properties i.e. `Count` and `Name`.

```
public class Cars
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count{ get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to unit test my repository layer and am not able to get the value of `Count` correctly.

Here is my unit test

```
public void GetCarStats()
{
   var mockRepo = new VehicleRepository();     
   var result = mockRepo.GetCarStats(Guid.Parse("9F733662-FP4E-69DC-AX600-A4C250F9E166"));

   Assert.NotEmpty(result);
   Assert.Equal(1, result.Count);   

   var cars= result.Where(x => x.Count > 0).Select( v => v.Count);

   Assert.Equal(6, cars);//This statement is failing
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement

```
var cars= result.Where(x=>x.Count>0).Select(v=>v.Count);
```

will give you an `IEnumerable<int>` and you are trying to compare it with a single number `6` , this should fail.

Depending on what you need, you can get the `First` element from your collection and compare it with `6` or you can use `Sum` to get the total number of count.

```
var cars= result.Where(x=>x.Count>0).Select(v=>v.Count).FirstOrDefault();
Assert.Equal(6,cars);//This statement is failing
```

If you are **interested in total number of records** returned against your condition `count > 0` then use `Count` instead of `Select(v=> v.Count)` like:

```
var cars = result.Where(x => x.Count > 0).Count();
```

or

```
var cars = result.Count(x=> x.Count > 0);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It was a very good explanation and helped me to understand Linq queries better.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a list of int to and int. Try this for sum of count:

```
var cars= result.Where(x=>x.Count>0).Sum(v=>v.Count);

Assert.Equal(6,cars);
```

and this for amount of results that have more than 0 cars:

```
var cars= result.Where(x=>x.Count>0).Select(v=>v.Count);

Assert.Equal(6,cars.Count());
```

Not sure which one you are looking for. This assumes you have setup the data for your test initially, otherwise the list will be empty anyway.

Comment: Based on the `Assert.Equal(1, result.Count);` it seems like the OP wants to verify that the `Count` of the one resulting `Cars` instance is 6.